# Return powershell variable value to c# application

Tags: c#, powershell

I am running powershell script from c#.

```
string scriptPath = "/script/myscript.ps1";
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptPath);
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

for example if my  **myscript.ps1** file below;

```
$test=4
$test++
$test
```

How to get the variable `test` value after executing the script. I need to get that value to my c# program.

Answer (score 4):

I know I am late to this, but in your script, you need to add `global:` in front of the variable you want to return in the Powershell script, so for example:

```
$global:test = 4
```

in Powershell script. In C# after you open the runspace, invoke the policy changer, set up the pipline, you do

```
var result = runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("test");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string variable_to_return_from_ps_script = "test"; 

// create Powershell runspace
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

//
// here you write the code to invoke the PS script, pipeline, pass parameters etc...
// just like the code you already have
//

// and here's how you retrieve a variable test from PS
var out_var = runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue(variable_to_return_from_ps_script);
Console.WriteLine("Variable ${0} value is: ", variable_to_return_from_ps_script);
Console.WriteLine(out_var.ToString());
```