# Powershell & C# to check if host available

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a c# code segment which processes a power-shell script. The following is the code segment:

```
Runspace objRunspace = null;
objRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
objRunspace.Open();
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.Runspace = objRunspace;
powershell.AddScript("my powershell script");
Collection<PSObject> objPS1 = powershell.Invoke();
if (objPS1.Count == 0)
{
    //I Assumes that the PC is down
}
```

In this case, if the login credentials are wrong or if that particular PC is not available, the `ObjPS1.count` will be zero. If that count is zero, I assumed that the host is unavailable. But with accuracy in mind, I want to identify both these (wrong credentials / host unavailable) situations separately. Is there a better way or different approach to achieve the same?

Comment: You can return the result of the operation from power shell see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467629/return-powershell-variable-value-to-c-sharp-application how to do this

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to test for? I think I see two tests - first, is the server online and second, do I have valid credentials. Split these tests - first test that it's online (from C# directly, with `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping`), then test the credentials (using whatever method is appropriate). There's no point in testing the credentials if the system isn't reachable in the first place. But unless you **must** use PowerShell for the whole thing, save it for just the portions that require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using following example,...

```
// invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

    // check the other output streams (for example, the error stream)
    if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
    {
        // error records were written to the error stream.
        // do something with the items found.
    }
```

Thanks & regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

To check for host, you can do this:

```
var host = powershell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue('Host');
if (host != null) {
    // This app has a host interface
}
```

Comment: Then the C# app does not implement the host UI interfaces.  See the docs on PSHostUserInterface - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface(v=vs.85).aspx