# C# get variable from powershell script

Tags: c#, variables, powershell

How can I get the powershell variable $test from a c# application?

I tried it like this:

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
runspace.Open();

RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
//Here's how you add a new script with arguments
Command myCommand = new Command(scriptFile);
CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("key", "value");
CommandParameter testParam2 = new CommandParameter("key", "value");
CommandParameter testParam3 = new CommandParameter("key", "value");
myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam2);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam3);

pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

// Execute PowerShell script
var results = pipeline.Invoke();
var resultVariable = runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("test");
```

`resultVariable` is `null`. But I filled it in powershell with an int (i.e. $test = 4).

Comment: Don't you need to use `GetValue("$test")` (with a `$`) instead?

Comment: This doesn't work either... I can call the function with the variable PSHome, this works. But not the variable I have set.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467629/return-powershell-variable-value-to-c-sharp-application

Comment: It's not. I have seen this post but the answer does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$global:test=4` in script or run script in same scope. By default script run in its own scope, so any variable changed in script does not visible outside.